# Changed folder structure - now Specflow .feature files are missing (only seeing .feature.cs)

Tags: specflow

I did some changes to our specflow structure in a new branch. VS didn't respond well and moved step bindings suddenly weren't found. So I stashed the changes and files moved and went back to a branch with no changes.

Now though, all the feature files that changed the path in the other branch do not generate a .feature file. Only the feature.cs file is shown.

All the feature files I did not move remain the same as before. I've cleared the cache and rebuilt the solution to no avail. I have no idea what is going on.

Any ideas?

*the little red symbol says "Ignored"

[image]

Comment: Click "Show all files" in the solution explorer panel. The other files might show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what was the problem exactly, but it was Git related. Someone files that were already deleted showed up again in the tree.

No real solution, but if all else fail, cloning origin will probably work.